# Import ERROR matplotlib in jupyter notebook on VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am very new to python and on stackoverflow, so please be indulgent with my questions. I had successfully installed matplotlib with the command pip install matplotlib without any errors and I tried to import it with the command:

`import matplotlib`

[here is the text code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKVL1.png)

and I also see this msg:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libXdmcp.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libxcb.1.1.0.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXdmcp.6.dylib: cannot load 'libXdmcp.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXdmcp.6.dylib: cannot load 'libXdmcp.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
```

I expected to have no issues

For information : i am on macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave)

Comment: Please try "pip install --user matplotlib" or "python3 -m pip install matplotlib --user".

Comment: Hi Saksham, it says "Requirement already satisfied" for both of your commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cannot load 'libXdmcp.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)

According to [this case](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6862) in github. This is an issue about pillow instead of matplotlib.

You can use the following way to install Pillow:

1. download .zip file and extract it.
2. use command `cd path\you\download\file`
3. uninstall the current Pillow with `python3 -m pip uninstall Pillow` or `python -m pip uninstall Pillow`
4. install from this new wheel with `python3 -m pip install Pillow-9.4.0-1-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl`

You can also install [.whl](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/files/10335998/Pillow-9.4.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl.zip) file directly then use command `python3 -m pip install Pillow-9.4.0-1-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl` to install it.

Comment: i already did that.... and it doens't work.... i am desperate....

Comment: @Saibot I read [this article](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6862). I guess you didn't provide a complete error report in the original text. This seems to be a problem with PIL, but your article didn't mention it. I updated my answer according to this issue.

Comment: If you meet the problem about installing this package, you can try the way which is mentioned in the github. Installing .whl file [here](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files) then install

Comment: Thanks you, i am going to try the pillow reinstalling pillow.

Comment: I found a solution, but i didn't have the reputation to post it : https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6862

Comment: can you edit your answer because you have to do the exact procedure :

    1 ) Download the zip and extract it
    2 ) cd to that directory in your Terminal
    3) Uninstall your current Pillow with python3 -m pip uninstall Pillow
    4) Install from this new wheel with python3 -m pip install Pillow-9.4.0-1-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl

reinstall pillow by pip install pillow DID NOT correct my problem. i will also edit my question by giving some detail like macOS version, blabla...

Comment: @Saibot I've edited my answer. You can install .whl file directly as well.

Comment: Thanks ! i don't have any reputation so i can't vote but i have mark your answer.